# Improving O(n^2) algorithm

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, linq

I have the following piece of code:

```
var keywordItems = adwordsService
  .ParseReport(report)
  .Where(e => e.Keyword.IndexOf('+') == -1);

var keywordTranslations = keywordTranslationService
  .GetKeywordTranslationsByClient(id);

model.KeywordItems = keywordItems
    .Where(e =>
    {
        int lastUnderscore = e.CampaignName.LastIndexOf('_');
        var identifer = e.CampaignName.Substring(lastUnderscore + 1);

        var translation = keywordTranslations
          .FirstOrDefault(t => t.translation == e.Keyword && 
                               t.LocalCombination_id == identifer);

        return translation == null;
    })
    .OrderBy(e => e.Keyword);
```

It receives an array and then filters each of these element based on whether or not they've already been seen before.

However, this runs pretty slow, as there's a lot of new elements, so I would like it, if someone can point me in the right direction regarding the best algorithm to use in this case.

Comment: You have two different inputs - `keywordItems` and `keywordTranslations` -
 so what is `n` here?

Comment: They're two lists of approximately same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple join will do the job - it uses hashset for matching between collections, which gives you O(1) for search operation:

```
from k in keywordItems
let identifer = k.CampaignName.Substring(k.CampaignName.LastIndexOf('_') + 1)
join t in keywordTranslations on
    new { k.Keyword, Id = identifer } equals
    new { Keyword = t.translation, Id = t.LocalCombination_id } into g
where !g.Any()
orderby k.Keyword
select k
```

To further improve performance you can move `identifier` extraction directly to the key creation. Thus you will omit introducing new range variable.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using *hashing*, e.g. `HashSet<T>` or `Dictionary<T>`. Providing that `translation` as well as `LocalCombination_id` are of type `string`:

```
  HashSet<Tuple<string, int>> keywordTranslations = 
    new HashSet<Tuple<string, string>>(keywordTranslationService
      .GetKeywordTranslationsByClient(id)
      .Select(t => new Tuple<string, int>(t.translation, t.LocalCombination_id)));

  model.KeywordItems = keywordItems
    .Where(e => !keywordTranslations.Contains(new Tuple<string, string>(
       e.Keyword,
       e.CampaignName.Substring(e.CampaignName.LastIndexOf('_') + 1))))
    .OrderBy(e => e.Keyword);
```